# Get data from main table by querying sub table and main table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've got table product and sub table series in one too many relation

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
   id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
   order: Sequelize.STRING
})

const Series = sequelize.define('series', {
   id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
   name: Sequelize.STRING,
})
```

Relation

```
Product.belongsTo(Series);
Series.hasMany(Product);
```

I want to get all products where series name is some text and product order name is some text.

```
exports.searchProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
   const name = req.body.name || ''
   const order = req.body.order || ''
   try {
      const series = await Series.findAll({
         where: {
            name: {[Op.like]: '%' + name + '%'}}
      });

      const products = await series.getProducts  //<= get stuck here
      res.status(200)
         .json({result: products})
   }
   catch (err) {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
         err.statusCode = 500
      }
      next(err);
   }
}
```

I managed to query series but get stuck to query product result with order name. So how can I query product result with order name? I tried to add where clause in `getProducts` but that come up with error `getProducts` is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
  cosnt products = await Products.findAll({
      where: {
          order: {[Op.like]: '%' + order + '%'}
      },
      include: [
          {
              model: Series,
              where: {
                    name: {[Op.like]: '%' + name + '%'}
              },
              required: true
          }
      ]
  })
```

Comment: hmm... yes that works.. I'm not sure if this can be used for complex nested querying though. Thanks

Comment: ```const products = await series.getProducts  //<= get stuck here```
You should invoke this method with for loop.
for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) { ...series[i].getProducts()... }